# Keep Format Settings in Lyx

Tags: formatting, lyx

I currently have a resume written in Lyx. I want to make some minor changes
to it and just change its content. However, I want to keep the same format
(i.e. the same margin, same indentation, etc.) I don't recall what settings 
I made before. How can make keep the old format settings?

Comment: Can't you simply copy the lyx file, rename it and make your changes in that copy? Margins, indention and other spaces, if different from the standard, can be checked in the document settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is extending @Martin H's suggestion:

- Take the `CV_old.lyx` file you have
- Edit it in a way that it becomes a kind of a template (keep the formats you like, the text you want to use as standard / start.....)
- In *Document | Settings* click on *Save as Document Defaults*
- Now save this template as (for example:) `CV.lyx`
- As root, move the file to `/usr/share/lyx/templates` or wherever your lyx templates are sitting

From here, you should have a template with exactly the settings you like for each CV you write.